# SQL - Row of IDs, fetch joined data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `garages` structured like this:

```
garageid | car1 | car2 | car3
```

The carN fields contain IDs from another table `cars`:

```
carN | make | color
```

Is there a way to get the list of colors for a specific garage in a single query?

The result would be:

```
garageid | color1 | color2 | color3
```

I realize this structure is not normalized, but the number of cars will never change. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you looking to have dynamic columns?

Comment: May i suggest that 'normalizing' the database as a 'garage id' with **separate entries** of: **car id | make | color** with a 'foreign key' of **garage id** would be more practical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing multiple columns with ids is usually not a good approach.  It is better to have one row per car.  That said, you can do what you want using multiple joins:

```
select g.garageid, c1.color as color1, c2.color as color2, c3.color as color3
from garages g left join
     cars c1
     on g.car1 = c1.carid left join
     cars c2
     on g.car2 = c2.carid left join
     cars c3
     on g.car3 = c3.carid;
```

The `left join` will still return the `garage` even when one or more of the car ids are `NULL`.

Comment: If there were 100 car<n>.id columms, would your answer be the same? Just curious - no judgement. what would the limit be?

Comment: I see. A little impractical since I actually have 11 'cars'. I'll normalize the database but thanks for the working answer!

Comment: @RyanVincent . . . Well, yes.  But I wouldn't structure data this way.  Read the first two sentences.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion is better to have a table t_garage_cars:

garageId carId

In this manner is simple to retrive data.

If this is not possible for some reason I believe you can only use a cursor may be with a temp table